# Count the rows of a table where the value is obtained from another table and display in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, count

I want to take the post_id from table 'posts' and use this value to count the rows in table 'comment_post' where the same column post_id is equal to the value from the table posts
These are my 2 tables:

`posts`

```
 id | post_id | title
----+---------+-------
 1  | 1       | title1
 2  | 2       | title2
 3  | 3       | title3
```

`comment_post`

```
 id | post_id | comment_id
---+----------+-----------
 1 | 1        | 26        
 2 | 1        | 27        
 3 | 2        | 28        
 4 | 1        | 29        
 5 | 3        | 30
```

User comments are stored in a separate table 'comments' and posts are published in the table `posts`.
I made a relationship between the two tables and called the table 'comment_post'.

I have a loop set up to return the posts in the browser

```
<div class="row">
            <?php              
            $i = 0; 
            foreach ($posts as $post):{
            if(++$i > 11) break;
            } 
            ?>
                <!-- post -->
                <div class="post col-xl-6">
                    <div class="post-thumbnail"><a href="single_post.php?post-slug=<?php echo $post['slug']; ?>"><img loading="lazy" src="<?php echo BASE_URL . '/static/images/' . $post['image']; ?>" alt="pcr test" class="img-fluid"></a></div>
                    <div class="post-details">
                    <div class="post-meta d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="date meta-last"><?php echo date("F j, Y ", strtotime($post["created_at"])); ?></div>
                        <?php if (isset($post['topic']['name'])): ?>
                        <div class="category">
                        <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL . 'filtered_posts.php?topic=' . $post['topic']['id'] ?>"><?php echo $post['topic']['name'] ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </div>
                    <a href="single_post.php?post-slug=<?php echo $post['slug']; ?>">
                        <h3 class="h4"><?php echo $post['title'] ?></h3></a>
                    <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $post['lead'] ?></p>
                    <footer class="post-footer d-flex align-items-center"><a href="#" class="author d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                        <div class="avatar"><img loading="lazy" src="static/images/avatar.jpg" alt="Jamie" class="img-fluid"></div>
                        <div class="title"><span>Jamie Aldus</span></div></a>
                        <div class="date"><i class="icon-clock"></i><?php echo date("j-m-y ", strtotime($post["created_at"])); ?></div>
                        <div class="comments meta-last"><i class="icon-comment"></i></div>
                        
                    </footer>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-line">
                    </div>
                </div>
                  <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
```

and in the line `<div class="comments meta-last"><i class="icon-comment"></i></div>`

I want to display the number of comments for each post.

I have tried all sorts of SELECT and COUNT(*) queries, but none seem to work.

A little help would be nice, thank you.

**Code for `$posts`**

```
function getPublishedPosts() {
    // use global $conn object in function
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE published=true ORDER BY created_at DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    // fetch all posts as an associative array called $posts
    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $final_posts = array();
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $post['topic'] = getPostTopic($post['id']); 
        array_push($final_posts, $post);
    }
    return $final_posts;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the wanted result?

Comment: I'm not sure what you've tried but presumably not: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment_post WHERE post_id = ?` (assuming you want to run a query for each iteration of the loop) (Or use `GROUP BY` and fetch all if you want to use one query?)

Comment: I don't know if I understood well, but something like this should do the trick: `SELECT p.post_id, COUNT(c.id) FROM posts p INNER JOIN comment_post c ON c.post_id=p.post_id GROUP BY p.post_id`.

Comment: I somehow need to get the post_id from the table 'posts' so I can run the SELECT COUNT(*) query in the loop

Comment: You need to show the code used to generate your results... (i.e. where does `$posts` come from?)

Comment: I updated the main question

Comment: Seems to me you could ditch `getPostTopic` as well.. Can you add that code too?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the comment post counts inside of your function by updating your SQL query with a left join and some grouping:

```
function getPublishedPosts($mysqli, $limit = 10) {
    $sql = "
        SELECT
            posts.*, COUNT(1) as commentCount
        FROM
            posts 
        LEFT JOIN
            comment_posts ON posts.id = comment_posts.post_id
        WHERE
            posts.published = true
        GROUP BY
            comment_posts.post_id, posts.id
        ORDER BY
            posts.created_at DESC
        LIMIT ?
    ";
    $query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param('i', $limit);
    $query->execute();
    $posts = $query->get_result();

    $final_posts = array();

    while($post = $posts->fetch_assoc()) {
        $post['topic']            = getPostTopic($post['id']);
        $final_posts[$post['id']] = $post;
    }

    return $final_posts;
}
```

**Notes**

1. It's best practice to not use `global $conn;` pass the `$conn` in when you invoke the function instead (much like passing the DB link to `mysqli_*`). You now use the function like:

   ```
   $posts = getPublishedPosts($conn);
   ```
2. I've changed the procedural style function calls to object style instead. Maybe it isn't your preference but it's easier to read and follow so I suggest learning it (others would suggest ditching `mysqli` it altogether and using `PDO` instead)
3. You can now access the number of comments per post at the field `commentCount`.
4. I've put a `$limit` parameter in the function call (with a default of `10`); because you have a limit in your for each loop (which you can now remove)

   ```
   $posts = getPublishedPosts($conn, 20); // Adding the second parameter changes the number of results returned, in this case 20 will be returned
   ```
5. I've changed your `$final_posts` to be indexed on the `post_id`. Maybe it isn't strictly necessary in this case but can make things easier down the road
6. I've changed the `for` loop in the function to a `while`: it basically does the same thing
7. As mentioned in the comments, I fully expect you can update the SQL Query to accommodate the `getPostTopic` as well (another `JOIN` most likely)